# selenium select checkboxes between checkboxes : Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

This is the how my HTML looks like:

```
    <tr>
     <td class = 'text-bar'> id </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" size = "20" value= 'Yes' id ="x_id1">
      </td>
    </tr>
  .
  .
  .
```

I have 19 checkboxes and I want to select checkboxes in-between.

what would be the easiest way to achieve that:

My current code looks like this which selects all the checkboxes right now. How do i add if condition to select particular checkboxes in-between ??:

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox']")
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        if not checkbox.is_selected():
            checkbox.click()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Appreciate your help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with to select particular checkboxes by converting them into a list. In my code, I am trying to select checkboxes between 3 and 15 (which is not dynamic but this is what I was looking for:

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type= 'checkbox']")
    chk = [checkbox for checkbox in checkboxes]
    for i in chk[4:15]:
        if not i.is_selected():
            i.click()
            time.sleep(1)
```